# How to change position of files in plupload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plupload

i m using plupload in my site for uploading files. I want user able to sort files (change position files) before start uploading.
for that i have attached jquery ui sortable plugin on the queue changed event that working fine but when we sort a file it will sort in the ui but actual position of file remain same. so the uploading start in their internal sequence. it there any way to sort files in plupload as I like.
pls tell me if anybody know

Comment: sorting in plupload work in the jquery ui wideget. add an option sortable:true in the jquery ui widget will work fine for this thing.
to add jquery ui widget add the jquery ui js, css and jquery.ui.plupload.js and jquery.ui.plupload.css which provided by the plupload

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if plupload supports custom sorting of queued files, or manually changing their index.
plupload is a typical flash-based multiple file uploader. The filedata is stored in flash (along with the order).

So changing the order in the DOM (with jquery) isn't going to affect the actual upload order.
In the [plupload documentation](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html) I read something about a **QueueChangedevent
public event QueueChanged(uploader:Uploader)**.

This event is fired when the upload queue is changed (files added or removed. you'll have access to uploader.files array. See if you can sort the array here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: plupload is not only the flash based uploader but it also support html4, html5, browerplus and more lib. and file data stored in the uploader class's files variable. anyway i have solved this problem thanks for your support.

Comment: I was assming you were using a multiple upload. All multiple uploaders for php and html4 use flash to select multiple files. It's because of the limitations with the input type'file' field in html4. html5 supports multiple file upload, but this is not yet supported in IE. Don't know what the case on that is in browserplus.